# How to control dimensions of empty arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to concatenate 1-D two arrays in Python, using numpy. One of the arrays might potentially be empty (a2 in this case). a1 and a2 are the results from some computation over which I have no control. When a1 and a2 are non-empty they both have shapes of the form (n,2), so concatenation is not a problem. However it could turn out that one of them is empty, in which case its size becomes (0,). Hence the concatenation throws up an error.

```
s1=array(a1).shape
s2=array(a2).shape
print(s1) #(5,2) 
print(s2) #(0,)
s3=hstack((a1, a2))
s3=concatenate((a1, a2), 0)
```

Error:
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

I see other stackoverflow questions where it is said that it is possible to concatenate an empty array. How do I ensure that the empty array's size is (0,2)? Can someone help me out?

Comment: what values have a1, a2 when error occurs?

Comment: Please confirm that the dimensions are (0,) and (5,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you what you need to know. It's not enough that the array is empty - they have to have the **same number of dimensions**. You are looking only at the first element of `shape` - but `shape` can have more than one element:

```
numpy.array([[]]).shape   # (1L, 0L)
numpy.array([[]]).transpose.shape  # (0L, 1L)
numpy.array([]).shape     # (0L, )
```

So you see, empty arrays can have different numbers of dimensions. This may be your problem.

**EDIT** solution to create an empty array of the right size is to `reshape` it:

```
a2.shape()      # (0L,)
a2 = a2.reshape((0,2))
a2.shape()      # (0L, 2L)
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, the array dimensions are (0,) and (5,) so it should be fine.

Comment: You are right. The dimensions are (5, 2) and (0,), but I do not control the dimensions of the empty array. How do I ensure the second dimension of a2 is 2?

Comment: If `a2` is empty, you can do `a2.reshape((0,2))` - it will create 2D empty array with second dimension 2.